# Find immediate unknown child element using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I need to retrieve the class of an element that is nested within an `<li>`, but I won't always know exactly what that element is.

```
<ul>
    <li class="featureItem">
        <ul class="class1 class2 class3">
            ...
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="featureItem">
        <div class="class2 class3 class4"></div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

What is the best method to select an immediate child of `$('featureItem')` when the child element is unknown?

Comment: Does `$('.featureItem :first-child').attr('class')` not work?  See http://api.jquery.com/first-child-selector/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do:

```
$('.featureItem').children().first().attr("class");
```

Comment: Added `.` on your selector. +1